# Update column data to null without writing each column name in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table XX_LOCATION with 20 columns. Out of this I want data in only 4 columns in rest 16 I want to update the column values to null.

How can 1 update statement be used for this i.e. I don't want to  write each column name of 16 columns in the update statement. Is there any other way out?

Comment: There's no short-cut here.

Comment: Or do you mean INSERT values? E.g. `INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES(val1, val2, val3, val4)`? Will set col5 to col20 to NULL (as long as no default values are specified for columns.)

Comment: Dirty way... fetch the columns names and create a dynamic sql...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I admit. I am having a little bit of fun with this one.

```
 BEGIN
       FOR eachrec IN (SELECT column_name
                         FROM user_tab_cols a
                        WHERE table_name = 'MYTABLE'
                          AND column_name NOT IN ('COL1', 'COL2', 'COL3'
                                                , 'COL4'))
       LOOP
          execute immediate 'update XX_LOCATION set ' || eachrec.column_name || ' = null';
       END LOOP;
    END;
```

Here is another possibility, this one with only a single execute immediate:

```
DECLARE
   l_cmd     VARCHAR2 (2000);
   l_comma   VARCHAR2 (1);
BEGIN
   l_cmd   := 'update xx_location set ';

   FOR eachrec IN (SELECT column_name
                     FROM user_tab_cols a
                    WHERE table_name = 'MYTABLE'
                      AND column_name NOT IN ('COL1', 'COL2', 'COL3'
                                            , 'COL4'))
   LOOP
      l_cmd     := l_cmd || l_comma || eachrec.column_name || ' = null';
      l_comma   := ',';
   END LOOP;
   execute immediate l_cmd;
END;
```

And finally, a completely automated solution to exclude N columns, without having to type the non-specified column names:

```
CREATE TYPE column_tt IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (30);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE nullify_columns (
   p_owner             IN            all_tab_cols.owner%TYPE
 , p_table             IN            all_tab_cols.table_name%TYPE
 , p_exclude_columns   IN OUT NOCOPY column_tt
)
AS
   l_cmd     VARCHAR2 (2000);
   l_comma   VARCHAR2 (1);
BEGIN
   l_cmd   := 'update ' || p_owner || '.' || p_table || ' set ';

   FOR eachrec IN (SELECT column_name
                     FROM all_tab_cols a
                    WHERE owner = p_owner
                      AND table_name = p_table)
   LOOP
      IF NOT eachrec.column_name MEMBER OF p_exclude_columns
      THEN
         l_cmd     := l_cmd || l_comma || eachrec.column_name || ' = null';
         l_comma   := ',';
      END IF;
   END LOOP;

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_cmd;
END;

CREATE TABLE totally_bogus_dude
(
   col1   VARCHAR2 (10)
 , col2   VARCHAR2 (10)
 , col3   VARCHAR2 (10)
 , col4   VARCHAR2 (10)
 , col5   VARCHAR2 (10)
);

DECLARE
   l_exclude   column_tt := column_tt ();
BEGIN
   l_exclude.EXTEND;
   l_exclude (l_exclude.COUNT)   := 'COL1';
   l_exclude.EXTEND;
   l_exclude (l_exclude.COUNT)   := 'COL2';
   l_exclude.EXTEND;
   l_exclude (l_exclude.COUNT)   := 'COL3';
   l_exclude.EXTEND;
   l_exclude (l_exclude.COUNT)   := 'COL4';

   FOR eachrec IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
                     FROM TABLE (l_exclude))
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (eachrec.COLUMN_VALUE);
   END LOOP;

   nullify_columns (p_owner => USER, p_table => 'TOTALLY_BOGUS_DUDE', p_exclude_columns => l_exclude);
END;
```